# Replacing Gas range knobs

Tags: range, knobs

How do people replace gas knobs on a range and why are they so expensive?

I have a Whirlpool gas range (Whirlpool 5.8CuFt GAS Slide-in Range with Center Oval Burner in Stainless Steel - WEG745H0FS) that I bought 4 years ago. It cost $1150 at that time.

During last year I have replaced two knobs and it cost me $50 each time from Whirlpool parts. I just realized that I've paid almost 10 percent of the cost I originally paid in knobs. Now I have a third knob going bad and I really don't want to shell out $50 again

So my question is, how do I replace them. I found a lot of OEM knobs on Amazon but they did not advertise my model as compatible. I even bought one thinking that it looked similar to the knobs that I had but it didn't fit.

Comment: A lesson I learned about range knobs is:  don't put them in the dishwasher...the paint comes off!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether gas or electric, the knobs are not magic items and there is no fundamental reason for them to cost very much. The only things that really matter are the diameter and shape (usually "D" shape) of the shaft. The labels are pretty standard, though they vary a bit - doesn't matter once the labels rub off (as they have on most of the knobs on my current gas cooktop).

I have replaced electric cooktop knobs with generic knobs with no problem. On my current gas cooktop I haven't had to replace them yet, only because I have an almost complete extra set from when I bought it (scratch and dent, had one knob broken or missing (can't remember which) and the store gave me the full set off of another cooktop).

There are even some replacement knob sets with multiple inserts for different size shafts. For $50 you can get a full set (or two).

Comment: Is Amazon the right place to order

Comment: Amazon is fine for this type of thing because the knobs are just outer mechanical parts. Very different from switches or gas valves etc. But a decent hardware store should have similar things and you could bring a knob to match the size and shape.